# « Parallèle de » ou « parallèle à »

Tags: prépositions

Quelle est la formule correcte : « *faire quelque chose en parallèle d'autre chose* », ou « *faire quelque chose en parallèle à autre chose* » ?

En mathématiques, une droite est parallèle *à* une autre, donc faut-il préférer la forme *parallèle à* ? Quelle est la justification grammaticale ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Il faut distinguer** :

**parallèle substantif**, féminin dans le sens géométrique ou temporel, masculin dans celui de comparaison (remarque : le mot désigne aussi certains instruments), d'où :

Une parallèle à un plan. Un parallèle de leurs vies.

**parallèle adjectif**, s'employant absolument, ou avec à :

Leurs vies ont été parallèles . Deux droites sécantes et parallèles à un plan P sont dans un plan Q parallèle au plan P.

**en parallèle de (ou avec) = parallèlement à, adverbe**

En parallèle de son métier de professeur de mathématiques, il était un bon pianiste amateur. (= parallèlement à son métier).

"En parallèle à son métier" me gêne un petit peu, car métier pourrait être considéré comme complément de nom, mais je ne vois pas de raison de proscrire cet emploi.

Comment: Pour être complet, dans la section substantif, il manquerait « établir un parallèle entre deux choses ».

Comment: Oui, et aussi "avec" : "Un parallèle avec le personnage de Monsieur Jourdain ...".

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais :

> Je fais deux choses en parallèle.

ou

> Je fais une chose parallèlement à autre chose.